# We have deployed the Flask application on the Apache server. But this is not working as we expected The problem is described below

Tags: python, apache, flask

We have deployed the Flask application on the Apache server. If I run the Flask app directly it will create a folder on the remote machine but if I run the same code on the Apache server it will give an error like access dined("PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: '\remotemachinename\test'\r, referer: http://localhost:8080/home").

```
from flask import Flask
import os
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/hello/<name>')
def hello_world(name):
    Folder_name = "\\\\remotemachinename\\{}".format(name)
    if os.path.exists(Folder_name):
        return folder_exists_message
    os.mkdir(Folder_name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

can you please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: `it will give an error like access dined` post the EXACT error. Also, I'm unsure if Apache allows you to create random files on your operating system

Comment: This is the exact error in apache error log file "PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: '\\remotemachinename\\test'\r, referer: http://localhost:8080/home"

Comment: What is the root directory at the apache server?

Comment: root directory is "C:\Apache24"

Comment: @DevarajGowda is there a reason you want to make folders?

Comment: Does your apache user has the read/write permissions on that network folder?
If not another possibility would be to mount the network folder as a local drive on that server using the right credentials.

Comment: @pitto I have full access.if i run the script directly trough flask i can able to create the folder

Comment: @Zun  Folder creation our task

Comment: Thanks to everyone who commented here. I have changed the default Apache service to my service account, which starts as a local administrator. After this it works fine

Comment: Well done, @DevarajGowda.

If provided input was helpful please consider to upvote and / or choose my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As observed in the comments I write here the final solution:

Please be sure that the default Apache service account has rights to write in the network share.

In this specific case the user decided to change the default Apache service account to his service account (local admin).